# converting strings to dates c++

Tags: c++, datetime, date

I'm using < time.h > to convert between strings and dates in c++.

```
int main() {
    string dateFormat = "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S";
    tm startDate, endDate;
    if (strptime("1-1-2004 01:01:01", &dateFormat[0], &startDate) == NULL) { exit(1); }
    if (strptime("1-1-2010 00:00:00", &dateFormat[0], &endDate) == NULL) { exit(1); }
    cout << "startDate: " << asctime(&startDate)
         << " endDate: " << asctime(&endDate) << endl;

    time_t startDate2 = mktime(&startDate);
    time_t endDate2 = mktime(&endDate);

    cout << "startDate: " << asctime(localtime(&startDate2))
         << " endDate: " << asctime(localtime(&endDate2)) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I get this as output:

```
startDate: Thu Jan  1 01:01:01 2004
 endDate: Thu Jan  1 01:01:01 2004

startDate: Thu Jan  1 01:01:01 2004
 endDate: Thu Jan  1 01:01:01 2004
```

Why is the start date the same as the end date? Also if anyone has a better way of doing this please speak up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. asctime uses a shared piece of memory to write the strings to. I have to copy that to another string so that it does not get overwritten.

```
int main() {
    string dateFormat = "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S";
    tm startDate, endDate;
    if (strptime("1-1-2004 01:01:01", &dateFormat[0], &startDate) == NULL) { exit(1); }
    if (strptime("1-1-2010 00:00:00", &dateFormat[0], &endDate) == NULL) { exit(1); }

    string sd1(asctime(&startDate));
    string ed1(asctime(&endDate));

    cout << "startDate: " << sd1
         << " endDate: " << ed1 << endl;

    time_t startDate2 = mktime(&startDate);
    time_t endDate2 = mktime(&endDate);

    string sd2(asctime(localtime(&startDate2)));
    string ed2(asctime(localtime(&endDate2)));

    cout << "startDate: " << sd2
         << " endDate: " << ed2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```